# What's the best way to refactor my code to implement composition in Rust?

Tags: design-patterns, rust, composition

The following has a lot of duplicated code. What's the best way to refactor it?

I'm coming from JavaScript where I use composition to achieve the same result, but in Rust it seems to me that I have to reimplement a lot of code.

I know there is a way using macros, but if the logic is more complex I'll end up with a large executable file since macros are inlined.

```
struct Shape {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

struct Circle {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    radious: i32,
}

struct Square {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
    width: i32,
    height: i32,
}

trait Advance {
    fn advance(&mut self);
}

impl Advance for Shape {
    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.x += 1;
    }
}

impl Advance for Square {
    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.x += 1;
    }
}

impl Advance for Circle {
    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.x += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello World!!");

    let mut shape = Shape { x: 0, y: 0 };
    let mut square = Square {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
    };
    let mut circle = Circle {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        radious: 5,
    };

    while shape.x < 10 {
        shape.advance();
        circle.advance();
        square.advance();
        println!("shape {}", shape.x);
        println!("circle {}", circle.x);
        println!("square {}", square.x);
        println!("---------------------");
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a03dd49ae06ce83b5dd27c4343fb9f5)

Comment: @hellow Please do not vote to close with a custom reason that "it belongs on Code Review". Nothing in the Stack Overflow rules justifies such a custom reason, and sloppy reasoning perpetuates inappropriate referrals. Not all questions about analyzing code are off-topic on Stack Overflow, and not all code review requests are on-topic on Code Review. Instead, vote to close as too broad or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @Zeta there are options for "it belongs to another stackexchange webpage", but codereview is none of them, so I thought I just use a custom reason for flagging it as such.

Comment: @hellow Yeah, that's [a known problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251568/ui-suggests-that-better-fit-elsewhere-is-a-valid-reason-for-closure). That being said: while the code could be on-topic on CR, the question as-is is currently off-topic on CR, as the required context is missing. [Code Review has a full guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for those cases, in case you're interested in some explanations.

Comment: This question has been cross-posted [to users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/best-way-to-refactor-this-code/23403/1), which is a better place for this kind of open-ended problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to extend a struct, but you can put common properties into another struct and your struct can consist from these common structs. Common behaviors can be triggered via these common structs like `Point`.

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct Point {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

struct Shape {
    point: Point,
}

struct Circle {
    point: Point,
    radious: i32,
}

struct Square {
    point: Point,
    width: i32,
    height: i32,
}

trait Advance {
    fn advance(&mut self);
}

impl Advance for Point {
    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.x += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut shape = Shape {
        point: Point::default(),
    };
    let mut square = Square {
        point: Point::default(),
        width: 10,
        height: 10,
    };
    let mut circle = Circle {
        point: Point::default(),
        radious: 5,
    };

    while shape.point.x < 10 {
        shape.point.advance();
        circle.point.advance();
        square.point.advance();
        println!("shape {}", shape.point.x);
        println!("circle {}", circle.point.x);
        println!("square {}", square.point.x);
        println!("---------------------");
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dbd1a2a5a091ce80a191be4351cdd490)